# Is it possible that twbx file created by tableau desktop can be published in web by tableau public?

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible that twbx file created by tableau desktop can be published in web by tableau public?

for example, I want to extract data from mysql and make dashboard in tableau desktop. And then I save the dashboard in  twbx format. Finally I want to download the twbx file in tableau public and publish into the web.

Answer (score 3):

The method to save a workbook to Tableau Public is outlined [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_workbooks_tableaupublic.htm):

> 1. With your workbook open in Tableau Desktop, select 
>      `Server > Tableau Public >  Save to Tableau Public.`
> 2. Sign in using your Tableau Public account.
> 3. Type a name for the workbook and click Save.

Currently there is no method to upload a twbx directly to Tableau Public. The method above is the typical method for publishing to any server; public, online, or on-premise.